# Can't build node server when build the project from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native

If I just type `react-native run-android`, everything is fine.

I can see the progress bar.
[image]

But If I build the project from Android Studio, there is no progress bar and my simulator shows the old version code, even it shows build successfully.

It is very strange, I found my node server doesn't start up.

I think it is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

I have to debug my project on native code with Android Studio.

Any one has meet the same issue ?

Comment: You may be using the release configuration in android studio. React-Native generates an android config that will use the bundler server only when running on debug mode. If you want to run your projet from Android Studio, run on debug mode, and be sure to start your bundler server with `npm start`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked my Android Studio Build Variants, app build variant is `debug`

Comment: I found the solution, I have to type `npm start` first, then run the project on Android Studio.  I have to run the node server manually.